# Why TabLayout always messing with tab order?

Tags: java, android

So I have `TabLayout` with `Pager` in my app which I assume is used properly but I have that little issue with it:

```java
TabLayout.Tab asd1 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab one");
TabLayout.Tab asd2 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab two");
TabLayout.Tab asd3 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab three");

tabLayout.addTab(asd1);
tabLayout.addTab(asd2);
tabLayout.addTab(asd3); 

pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
InspectionRecordPager adapter = new InspectionRecordPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my Pager is nothing special it looks like this

```java
public class InspectionRecordPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  private int tabCount;

  public InspectionRecordPager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
    super(fm);

    this.tabCount = tabCount;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i){
      case 0:
        return new Fragment1();
      case 1:
        return new Fragment2();
      case 2:
        return new Fragment3();
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
  }
```

And also I have button where I set up `onClickListener` and I am doing something like this

```java
button.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v){
    Log.wtf("PAGER", pager.getChildAt(0) + " " + pager.getChildAt(1) + " " + pager.getChildAt(2));
  }
}
```

And when I run app and press the button I am getting:

```
E/PAGER: android.widget.TableLayout{e83b671 V.E...... ........ 1200,0-2400,1265 #7f090031 app:id/frag_one} android.widget.TableLayout{7c15d8c V.E...... ........ 2400,0-3600,1265 #7f0900b6 app:id/frag_two} null
```

Why is there a null?

When I change `page` in `pager` to second and click button I am getting

```
E/PAGER: android.widget.TableLayout{4915c18 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1200,1265 #7f09003e app:id/frag_one} android.widget.TableLayout{e83b671 V.E...... ........ 1200,0-2400,1265 #7f090031 app:id/frag_two} android.widget.TableLayout{7c15d8c V.E...... ......ID 2400,0-3600,1265 #7f0900b6 app:id/frag_three}
```

No, null why? I think that should be default behaviour independent of selected tab.
And also when I select third tab and press button something really strange going on the output is

```
E/PAGER: android.widget.TableLayout{691c2a9 V.E...... ........ 1200,0-2400,1265 #7f090031 app:id/frag_two} android.widget.TableLayout{d15902e V.E...... ........ 2400,0-3600,1265 #7f0900b6 app:id/frag_three} null
```

And null again? What is going on? I am trying to understand this problem for few hours now, not sure what is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you debug this using the debugger and not using `Log`s

Comment: check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) in the docs

Answer (score 2):

> Why is there a null?

Because `ViewPager` has not set up the third page yet. `ViewPager` does not need a third child at this point, because you can only swipe in one direction.

> No, null why?

Because `ViewPager` now has three pages, because you can swipe in both directions.

> I think that should be default behaviour independent of selected tab

The developers of `ViewPager` disagree with you, apparently.

> And null again? What is going on?

`ViewPager` does not need a third child at this point, because you can only swipe in one direction.

How `ViewPager` manages its children is part of the internal implementation of `ViewPager`. Nobody should be relying on any particular behavior of `ViewPager` with respect to children. IOW, stop calling `getChildAt()` on a `ViewPager` and expecting particular results. If you want to work with widgets on a particular page, have your `Fragment` for that page do that, as that `Fragment` has direct access to its own widgets.

Comment: Thanks you for explanation. That help me solved the issue, also @Mohammed Alaa give me an idea. Thanks.